# How to use Functions/Methods that require 'driver' parameter in Page Factory Model

Tags: java, selenium, appium, page-factory

In my framework i have baseTest class and BasePageObject class 
Every Page extends BasePO
Thing is : a lot of my methods on Pages need to use driver instance. I have method `getDriver()` and i use it 'n' times on every page
This result in Appium calling the getSession for 120 times per 5 min session
Because i use explicit wait(see code):

```
[debug] [MJSONWP (ae82d29b)] Calling AppiumDriver.getSession() with args: ["ae82d29b-c0af-46f9-bb13-d6ecc8ff5a00"]
2019-10-10 03:22:45:681 - [debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'getSession'
```

How to solve this problem?

I`m not sure what to try without changing whole framework

```
public class BasePO {

    WaitUtils waitUtils;
    AssertionUtils asrt;
    public BasePO() {
        asrt = new AssertionUtils();
        waitUtils = new WaitUtils();
        loadProperties();
        initElements();
    }
     private void initElements() {

        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(getDriver()), this);
    }
    private void loadProperties() {

    }

    protected IOSDriver<IOSElement> getDriver() {
        return IOSDriverManager.getThreadLocalDriver();
    }
}
```

*Driver Manager*

```
public class IOSDriverManager {
    public static ThreadLocal<IOSDriver<IOSElement>> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<IOSDriver<IOSElement>>();

    public static DesiredCapabilities getIOSCaps() {
     Here Are my Caps
    }

    public static IOSDriver<IOSElement> getThreadLocalDriver() {
        IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = webDriver.get();
        if (driver == null) {
            createThreadLocalWebDriver();
            driver = webDriver.get();
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public static void createThreadLocalWebDriver() {
        IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = null;
             try {
                driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://" + getProperty("accessUser") + ":" + getProperty("accessKey") + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), getIOSCaps());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://" + getProperty("accessUser") + ":" + getProperty("accessKey") + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), getIOSCaps());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    System.out.println("IOS Driver is not created..!, Please check capabilitis or make sure Appium Server is running.");
                }
                return;
            }


        webDriver.set(driver);
    }
```

*Any Page*

```
public class dashboardPage extends BasePO {

    @iOSXCUITFindBy( id = "dashboardScreen")
    private MobileElement dashboardScreen;

  public boolean isDashboardScreen(){
        waitUtils.waitForElementToBeVisible(dashboardScreen, getDriver());
        boolean flag =dashboardScreen.isDisplayed();
        return flag;
    }
```

May Be it possible to have less getSession calls without shrinking amount of explicit waits ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in my own framework by adding a `protected` WebDriver instance and a `protected` constructor in `BasePageObject` which assigns the WebDriver instance. Then, your other PageObjects inherit from BasePageObject, and you can implement another constructor for the PageObject that takes WebDriver as an argument.

When you initialize PageObjects, you can pass your test case's WebDriver instance into the PageObject, so you won't have to call `getDriver()` all the time. You can use this WebDriver instance to perform actions in your PageObjects, and then your test cases can call PageObject methods without any `getDriver()`.

Here's what my framework looks like in C#, starting with `BasePageObject`:

```
public class BasePageObject
{
    // protected WebDriver instance
    protected IOSDriver<IOSElement> Driver { get; }

    protected BasePageObject(IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver)
    {
        Driver = driver;
    }
```

Then, a regular PageObject denoted `SomePageObject`:

```
// inherit from BasePageObject
public class SomePageObject : BasePageObject
{
    // implement protected constructor from BasePageObject
    public SomePageObject(IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }

    // we can use the PageObject's driver instance as such
    public void DoSomethingWithDriver()
    {
        // this is protected WebDriver instance from BasePageObject above
        Driver.FindElement(SomeLocator);
    }
}
```

Now, tying it all together, here's how it looks in a test case:

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    // initialize your driver somehow
    IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = getThreadLocalDriver();

    // declare your PageObject, passing in your Driver instance
    SomePageObject myPageObject = new SomePageObject(driver);

    // now you can call PageObject methods as such
    myPageObject.DoSomethingWithDriver();
}
```

This is all very generic, and will need to be modified to suit your needs, but this is the design pattern that I have followed in all of my test frameworks with good results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use page factory initialization methods like this. For your every UI page use separate class and then use page factory in the constructor..

```
public class MainPage {
 IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver;

//constructor to initialize MainPage Class with IOSDriver with pageFactory design pattern
ProgrammesPage prog_page;
public MainPage(IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver) {
       this.driver = driver;
      // PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
       PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
   }
}
```